# Scroll all elements in an Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have an activity in Android with two main views: a header layout with some text boxes, and a view group which is an own implementation of a grid of unequal height elements. As you can see in the picture:

[image]

I would like to be able to scroll not only the elements in the view, but the whole activity. I could not use setHeaderView for the list since it is not a ListView, it is a subclass of ViewGroup. I am not able to achieve this :-(

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#E0E0DE"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/layout_action_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/background"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/layout_search_view"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_location_info" />

            <com.tenea.turipolis.UnequalGridView
                android:id="@+id/listPictures"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your support,

Answer (score 2):

Surround your whole layout with a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "ScrollViews can only have one child widget. If you want more children, wrap them in a container layout."

Comment: Use the layout you use currently as only children of the ScrollView. That's what I ment with "surround your whole layout".

Comment: Hi dst, that is not enough since I need to stretch the ViewGroup. How can I do it in order to be able to scroll to the end of the ViewGroup?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment... Your ViewGroup and your LinearLayout (or whatever Layout you're using) should have a `layout_height` of `wrap_content`... or do you have controls at the bottom? In that case, [use layout_weight and fillViewport](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout in:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

// your layout here

</ScollView>
```

You can only have one child widget so for example:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    // your layout here

    </LinearLayout>

</ScollView>
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your comment. It works but it is not what I am tryint to do. The last thing is that I need to stretch the ViewGroup to the end in order to be able to scroll the whole list. I mean, with your approach I can scroll but I NEED to fix the height of the ViewGroup.

Comment: Not 100% what it is you need, without seeing all your code it's hard. Try changing the layout_height in the linear layout to "fill_parent"? Maybe other views need that set too?

Comment: add android:fillViewport="true" to your scrollview xml properties